# How can I create a macro that find, select and cut columns, and paste them in another worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, automation, multiple-columns

Another day, another problem. I think it is easy to make this thing work, but I just don't know how to go further now.

## The issue:

On work we get excel sheets from our customers. In this sheet, they put detailled information, organised in each column, e.g. the first column contains customernumbers, the second column contains names, the thirth column addresses etcetera. The first row contains the description of the columns, like: "Customernumbers", "Names", "Addresses" etcetera.

The problem is, not every customer sents us this information in the right order or with the same description, e.g. some people call the column with Customernumbers, numbers or pupilnumber. Also, the columns are not always in the same order. Sometimes they put Addresses in the first column, sometimes they put names in the first column.

We have to manualy cut and paste every column in our own excel sheet in the right order, so that our software can read everything and put it in the database (no not mysql, else i had made already a script for mysql).

## The Question:

How can I detect what is written in every column and automatically cut and paste that column in the  right column of our excel worksheet. E.g. detect that the thirth column is about Customernumbers and paste them in the Customernumber column in our worksheet.

## Ideas:

1.) I was thinking and making a solution with php en mysql, were the excel worksheet will be uploaded in xml format, so that a php script can run and read this xml file, so that it finally can be stored in a mysql database. After that, we can create a xml file, by writing the information from the database to an xml file, with the columns in the right order.

2.) After long thinking and testing, i realized this would take to much time and is to complicated for something so easy. Instead, I tried to make something in VBA. I found useful scripts, and learned that VBA can do something I want. The only thing is, the web is to big to find what I exactly want and I only know the basics of VBA, however I would like to learn more about it, this is something that I need in a short time.

Comment: too global. get down with your particular problem, modify your post, show your code, then we will help

Comment: I can envision two ways to do this with VBA. Either create a macro to read the columns in the customer's spreadsheet and then use an if statement to say if this or this or this, then 'Customernumber'.

The other option could be to have the macro read the columns in the file and ask for user input to say, Yeah that column is the 'Names' column. Then have the macro move the data to the appropriate area.

Comment: A completely different idea - Create a template sheet you send through to your customers (or a web-form or something along those lines) and have them fill that in for you... The simplest solution is usually to standardize the input you receive moreso than try and figure out how they put things together... Not what you asked for, but hope it might get you thinking...

Comment: @Scheballs Do you have a sample file for me of one of those ideas? Or could you guide me making such a script?

Comment: If you can share with me a sample of the file you are working with I might be able to help you. The logic in Conditional Macros like this are very specific for each case.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with John that the best solution for the future would be to give the customers a standard template.

But for the purposes of your current issue, try to classify each column based off of its contents. For example:
- names start with capital letters, and tend to have one to two spaces delimiting first, middle, last names
- addresses tend to start with three-four digits and are followed by a series of letters
- ID's tend to be only numerical characters

Take these characteristics of each category, and go down a few rows in each column to see which of these categories the data fits best.

This should allow you to identify each column, and from there it should be easy to select columns and shuffle them around.